# Creating a linux symlink on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, symlink

I'm working with a large distributed server with different platforms, and need all of my computers to be able to communicate with the hub server and create symbolic links in its filesystem. Is there a command which will create a link compatible with non-NTFS file-systems (something akin to ln -s in linux/unix)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using **mklink**

for example if you are somewhere in c:\games and would like to make a symlink "tmp" to c:\temp

```
mklink /D tmp "c:\temp"
```

symbolic links work in (at least) Windows7 and are called **junctions**

Answer (score 0):

NTFS supports symbolic links, check it out: [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)
FAT32/FAT16 doesnt support them